# How do the (presumably sync) loop runners launch the async event loop?

Tags: python-3.x

Where is the implementation interface in Python documented that allows the async loop runners (from trio, asyncio, curio) to start the whole shebang?

We know that sync functions cannot call async ones and yet the async implementations have a magic function that starts the whole event loop, e.g.:

```
trio.run(some...async...fun)...

docstring: except that :func:`run` can (and must) be called from a synchronous context.
```

Googling 'python start an async event loop' refers to asyncio documentation,  which is a specific implementation.

Are the asyncio/trio/curio loop runners all hand-crafted to breach the sync->async wall?

Answer (score 1):

You can call async functions from a non-async context, you merely cannot `await` them. They return an awaitable object, just like a function that yields returns a generator object. These objects can be manipulated programmatically, and in particular you can build an event loop. But the event loop doesn't just consider awaitable objects, but should also take into account events from I/O operations to decide when an awaitable should continue.

Python's core `asyncio` module provides both the necessary interfaces and and a default event loop implementation.